# Standalone mesos master behind load balancer EC2

Tags: mesos

I have a mesos master behind a load balancer and a mesos agent that tries to connect to the mesos master via the load balancer

Everything is good when the agent directly connects to the master by providing the --master flag but as soon as I change the `--master` to point to the load balancer (dns entry not the LB IP) I keep getting the following error repeatedly on my agent

```
I0223 11:16:55.776448  4945 slave.cpp:1416] Detecting new master
I0223 11:16:55.796245  4947 slave.cpp:6456] Got exited event for master@xx.xx.xx.xx:8082
W0223 11:16:55.796283  4947 slave.cpp:6461] Master disconnected! Waiting for a new master to be elected
```

I don't see any logs in master

```
mesos master port:8082
load balancer listener:8082->8082
mesos agent port:5052
```

We use the classic load balancer that does not preserve the IP

I then tried advertising the agent IP & Port but that didn't help either

I also tried setting `--hostname, --advertise_ip & --advertise_port` on master but that didn't help either

Has anyone faced this issue? What should be the right values for `--advertise_ip, --advertise_port`

I'm not using the standard mesos master/agent ports FYI

At this point I've tried all sorts of combinations

Answer (score 0):

- `hostname` = DNS name
- `advertise_ip` = IP DNS resolves to
- `advertise_port` = External port